# ios - edit NSMutableAttributedString while keeping HTML properties

Tags: html, ios, nsattributedstring

I have a text with HTML format and I want to use this text in my iOS app. I'm using `NSAttributedString` to maintain the properties the text has via the HTML tags (such as `<strong></strong>`). The thing is, `[NSAttributedString initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:]` converts the text with the default font as Times New Roman. I tried using an `NSMutableAttributedString` to change the font to `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:]`, but it destroys the properties it has via the HTML tags. How can I work around this? Is there a way to change the default font?

**EDIT:**
For example, the text I'm trying to parse is as follows:

```
"Activities are typically <strong>directed at a group of people</strong> rather than individuals"
```

The code below parses it into an HTML text with Times New Roman:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* itemWithStyle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding) documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Output:

> Activities are typically **directed at a group of
>   people** rather than individuals

What it looks like when I print it:

```
Activities are typically {
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0xf1b34e0> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}directed at a group of people{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x9a8aa10> font-family: \"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
} rather than individuals{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0xf1b34e0> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

When I add the following piece of code, the text loses its attributes.

```
[itemWithStyle addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]} range:NSMakeRange(0, itemWithStyle.length)];
```

Comment: I don't get what your problem is. Are you trying to convert HTML formatted text into attributed string by stripping the HTML tags but keeping attributes?

Comment: Could you show us you code? Exemple, how did you tried changing the font? And could you log the attributedString, before and after?

Comment: I added the code I wrote and its outputs.

Comment: Could you log the attributedString? Not the output and how it's rendered, how it's logged/interpreted?

Comment: Ok. I'd suggest you get inspired with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153156/find-attributes-from-attributed-string-that-user-typed/23153221#23153221 As you see the log, you'll see that the "bold" part is inside the font, so your font change will erase it.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and solved with this:

```
NSMutableString * content = [[NSMutableString alloc] 
initWithString:@"<div style='font-size:15px; font-family: HelveticaNeue'>"];
[content appendString:self.article.content];
[content appendString:@"</div>"];
```

not sure if there is a "better" way to do it, but this did the trick for me