# Attributed String UILabel text is shrunken

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am writing an app that requires labels w/ musical accidental symbols, called sharp and flat (♯ and ♭, respectively). Specifically, I need a label that says c♯. It is irrelevant to the question what these two symbols mean within a musical context. My app's main font is Open Sans. However, because Open Sans doesn't specify a character for the sharp and flat symbols, it uses a generic sharp and flat symbol that I find unattractive. However, I know that Helvetica Neue (or the iOS system font) has some well made symbols for sharp and flat, so I decided to change the label's text to an attributed string so I could make the c Open Sans, and the ♯ Helvetica Neue (both size 24). I did this through the interface builder. Even though everything looks exactly the way I want in the storyboard, when I launch it in the iOS Simulator, the labels with attributed strings are significantly shrunken from the other labels. I should note that the label has 3 AutoLayout constraints, though these contrasts are positionally related only, not size related.

**Things I have tried (unsuccessfuly):**

- Using only one font
- Doubling the font size (was too big)
- Removing autolayout constraints

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain how to correctly create these labels. I am happy to provide any more information that is needed.

Thank you

Comment: I added Open Sans in to the files and added it to the .plist. It works on the generic labels and is in the storyboard as a selectable font.

Comment: Okay, excellent. Can you put a screenshot somewhere or post an example project on github? There need to be enough info so that others can see and reproduce the problem...

Comment: Why did using one font not work, what was the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you are using several labels next to each other to achieve your result, is that so? As matt stated please provide more information, add it to your question..

Comment: @matt, I think you misunderstood my comment. Adding it to the project did not fix the problem, I was simply saying that I had already done that because that negates the fact that it is not a built-in system font. In response to my lack of pictures, my reputation is too low.

Comment: @Zaph, I am not using multiple labels, as that would defeat the purpose of an attributed string. I did, however, figure out my own answer. See below.

Comment: No, I understood perfectly. Read again what I asked you to do, please. Do you want help or not?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. I misunderstood your comment. I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that the problem is that NSAttributedString does not (yet) support custom fonts through Interface builder. It looks like I will have to subclass. This question essentially boils down to be the same as this one: [Attributed string with custom fonts in storyboard does not load correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925914/attributed-string-with-custom-fonts-in-storyboard-does-not-load-correctly)

Comment: That's not at all what that question is about. It says that showing your text _in Xcode_ doesn't work for custom fonts. But NSAttributedString certainly does support custom fonts.

Comment: Not through storyboard. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Okay, I see your point. I have never liked the Xcode interface for making an attributed string so I've never used it. If I want to make an attributed string I always make it in code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind for the future. It appears like I'm going to have to do this with a custom IBDesignable class. I could probably just do it with a regular subclass but I like for my Storyboard to look the same as the actual build (pet peeve I guess?).