# Text Formatting Using UITextView

Tags: ipad, fonts, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITextView` where user enter data. I have a format bar below which has 
bold, italic, underline and other options like alignment etc. 
After a lot of search and testing I came to know that `NSString` don't support such bold, italic styling instead `NSAttributedString` should be used but I use `NSAttributedString` I am unable to make the selected text bold and italic at the same time.

My code is like this

```
NSMutableAttributedString *textViewText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:textView.attributedText];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if(textBoldBtn){

        UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:textView.font.pointSize];
        NSDictionary *boldAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:boldFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

        [dict addEntriesFromDictionary:boldAttr];          
    }
    if(textItalicBtn){

        UIFont *italicFont = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:textView.font.pointSize];

        NSDictionary *italicAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:italicFont forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
        [dict addEntriesFromDictionary:italicAttr]; 
    }   
    attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:dict];     
    [textViewText appendAttributedString:attributedText];
    textView.attributedText = textViewText;

    return true;
}
```

Using this technique it only takes the last font in dict when both buttons are pressed.

I have gone through a link on stack overflow where they use fontDescriptor of Label to make the text both italic and bold but note I don't want to use any label. I am using `UITextView`. I have also gone through 
`[textView setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:YES];`
But I want my own functions. I have also seen several *EGOTextView* and *TextEdit* for iOS but I strictly want this for iPad. I only want to use `UITextView`.

Kindly tell if there is any way using attributed string to make text both italic bold and even underline at the same time or any way to customize the functions of textView personal EditingTextAttributes functionality.

Thanks in Advance.

*App has to be uploaded to app store so no private frameworks required because they would cause rejection of app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a some issues.

First:
Attributes are a NSDictionary. That means works with key/value, and the key is unique!
So when, you use `addEntriesFromDictionary:`, the doc says:

> If both dictionaries contain the same key, the receiving dictionary’s
>   previous value object for that key is sent a release message, and the
>   new value object takes its place.

And when you want to apply bold and italic effect in your code, you think that you have:

> Key                 — Value
>   NSFontAttributeName — theBoldFont
>   NSFontAttributeName — theItalicFont

Whereas you replace the bold font with the italic one.

Second:
Since Bold AND Italic are a attribute "hidden" in `UIFont`, if you want to apply the both effect, you have to find a font which is italic AND bold. That why, underlining (`NSUnderlineAttributeName`) can be added without encountering your issue with bold and italic.
You may look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153156/find-attributes-from-attributed-string-that-user-typed/23153221#23153221) to know how to do about it.
So you may code some logic like this:

```
if (textItalicBtn && textBoldBtn)
{}
else if (textItalicBtn)
{}
else if (textBoldBtn)
{}
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can use (textItalicBtn && textBoldBtn) condition but that would cost me use of lots of if and else statements in my code as I am creating an editor with many other options as well. I was in search of some message to pass to the textView with which I can make it bold and italic at the same time but so long I have come to conclusion that it is not possible. I have to use English like BoldItalic and ifElse statements. Thanks a lot for your response and help. I appreciate.