# Not getting bold and italic words in SFUIText Font in attributed string

Tags: html, nsattributedstring

Hi I have a UILabel named questionLabel

```
let exStr = "SOME HTML STRING CONTAINING BOLD AND ITALIC WORDS"

var exAttrStr = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data: exStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                    options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, namedNSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                    documentAttributes: nil)

exAttrStr.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 51/255, green: 53/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 1), range: NSRange(location:0,length:exAttrStr.length))

exAttrStr.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName , value: SharedConstants.textFontSFUITextRegular(15), range: NSRange(location:0,length:exAttrStr.length))

questionLabel.attributedText = exAttrStr
```

I am setting the font as `SFUIText` regular. As I am adding attributes to the `exAttrStr` the bold and italic part of the attributed text is being overwritten. Is there a way I could get the bold and italic words using the `SFUIText` font family.

Comment: Bold and Italic are inside the `NSFontAttributedName` (and there can be only one `NSFontAttributeName`'s value for a given range). So you have to enumerate the `exAttrStr` for its already `NSFontAttributedName`, check if it's bold and/or italic, and apply then the corresponding `SFUITextFont` corresponding.

Comment: You can mix solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546844/attributed-text-replace-a-specific-font-by-another-using-swift/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941064/change-uitextview-font-w-o-removing-bold-underline-italics-formatting/