# Displaying html tags inside UILabel with specified Font

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, uifont

How to display below text in `UILabel`

```
While <em>La La Land </em>is a film emphasising the problems
```

I tried using below code but it is not displaying the correct format of text which is inside `<em>` tag (italic rendering) when used with specified font.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrHTMLText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[yourHTMTextHere dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
[attrHTMLText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:yourLabel.font range:NSMakeRange(0, attrHTMLText.length)];
[attrHTMLText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, attrHTMLText.length)];
Label.attributedText = attrHTMLText;
```

Comment: It's because the Italic effect is INSIDE the NSFontAttributed. So when you replace it, you replace the WHOLE font, with a none italic one. You have to iterate it, and find the corresponding font (if it's italic, put your italic custom one, etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find attributes from attributed string that user typed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153156/find-attributes-from-attributed-string-that-user-typed)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some part of text itallic then you can do this by using `NSMutableAttributedString`

```
NSMutableAttributedString *strText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"While La La Land is a film emphasising the problems"];
[strText addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
              value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Italic" size:22]
              range:NSMakeRange(7, 16)];
[label setAttributedText: strText];
```